# cordova: changing the base href make the app "violates the following Content Security"

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy

I'm using cordova app and had to use `pushstate`. so i had to change the base tag to the following `<base href="file://android_asset/www/">`

now the problem i'm facing is i have this error "Refused to load the script 'file://android_asset/www/cordova.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy"
it also refuses to load my other js files and css files who live in the www folder.

the "Content-Security-Policy" is the following :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: * 'unsafe-eval';
      script-src filesystem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://js.stripe.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://unpkg.com;
      style-src filesystem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://unpkg.com https://fonts.gstatic.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://unpkg.com data: data: ; media-src * 'self' data: content: blob:; img-src * 'self' data: content: blob: cdvphotolibrary: android-webview-video-poster:;
      object-src 'self';">
```

even tho I added `filesystem` to content-security-policy it still doesn't want to load the files

[image: here is a screenshot of the errors]

I try to add the scripts in the index.html like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.87af84487a1e0b8e190c.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.04776a3073ee0076cddd.bundle.js"></script>
```

note that everything was working just fine before introducing the `pushstate` in my app.

P.S.: I use aurelia as a javascript framework